# How to make modal popup after button pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I went online and some research on how i could make my sign up modal pop up once someone presses the signup button n my navbar, however i was unable to come across any information on how to do that. I know it most likely uses JS, however i dont have much knowledge with js.

I did try to experiment with some js lines that could make it appear, however it only translated it, which didnt look too well. im trying to get it to show up directly in the middle of the users screen, and while it is up, only allow the user to scroll between the top and bottom of the modal, if the users screen is small. if it is big enough to view the entire modal, i dont want the user to be able to scroll at all until either they close the signup modal or they continue with the signup process. Ive included a picture of the modal, included the html code for the modal, and the css code for the modal. Remember i dont want the background to be interactable while the modal is open.

[Image of my sign up modal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUn2w.png)

`<div class="modal modal-sheet position-static d-block bg-body-secondary p-4 py-md-5 signup-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalSignin">

```
    <h2>Register your Account</h2>
    
  

  <div class="modal-body p-5 pt-0">
    <form class="">
      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-3 cbs-form input-group-custom-field" id="usernameInput" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="on" required>
        <label for="usernameInput">Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input type="email" class="form-control rounded-3 cbs-form input-group-custom-field" id="emailInput" placeholder="name@example.com" autocomplete="on" required>
        <label for="emailInput">Email address</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input type="password" class="form-control rounded-3 cbs-form input-group-custom-field" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="on" required>
        <label for="passwordInput">Password</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input type="password" class="form-control rounded-3 cbs-form input-group-custom-field" id="confirmPasswordInput" placeholder="Password-Confirm" autocomplete="on" required>
        <label for="confirmPasswordInput">Confirm Password</label>
      </div>
      <input class="" type="checkbox" id="agreementCheckbox" name="Agreement Checkbox" required>
      <label class="text-center d-inline" for="agreementCheckbox"><span>I agree to the <a class="gray text-links" title="Terms and Conditions" href="https://www.termsfeed.com/live/7f2a7964-ad07-4450-9cc5-b4435160db61">Terms and Conditions</a> and <a class="gray text-links" title="Privacy Policy" href="https://www.termsfeed.com/live/51c49715-5a49-477f-aa7b-d431b74dde6c">Privacy Policy</a></span></label>
      <button class="w-100 mb-2 mt-2 btn btn-lg rounded-3 btn btn1" type="submit">Next</button>
      <div class="text-center">
                <p>Already have an account?<a title="Sign In" href="login.php" class="gray text-links">
                    Sign In
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
      <hr class="my-4">
      <h2 class="fs-5 fw-bold mb-3 text-center">Use a third-party to create your account.</h2>
      <button class="w-100 py-2 mb-2 btn rounded-3 border google-signup" type="submit">
        Continue with Google
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>`
```

`/* Sign up Modal */ .signup-modal-background { background-color: #222022; }`

Update. I got the modal to work. Thanks to everyone who helped! I posted the code used to get it to work, for anyone else who was having the same issue as i was.

```
    `<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Launch demo modal</button>`

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: Did you look at the examples from [the official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/)?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, _specific_ question. Also, spend the time to get familiar with the post editor and fix up your formatting. It's not difficult. Help us help you.

Comment: Alright. Im new to stack overflow, so im still getting a hang of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually describing the native bootstrap's modal's behavior. I'm not sure I'm understanding your problem well but:

Given a modal with the id `#modalSignin`, you should implement the signup button like so:
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalSignin"> ... </button>`

**OR** if for whatever reason you can't use the data-bs-target attribute, you should then use a specific event listener:

```js
$('#your-signup-button-id').on('click', function() {
    var modalToggle = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('the-modal-id'))
    modalToggle.show()
});
```

Alternative using vanilla JS:

```js
document.getElementById('your-signup-button-id').addEventListener('click', function() { 
    var modalToggle = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('the-modal-id'))
    modalToggle.show()
});
```

This should do it as long as you don't have any css rule that could break the native behavior (ie. if the user can scroll on the main content for example)

See more here: [Bootstrap 5 modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#usage)

Comment: In these examples you're recreating the modal on each click. That probably isn't right. Have a look at the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#via-javascript).

Comment: this does sort of work. when i click on the button, it takes me to the modal, however the screen is dimmed out whenever i get sent to the modal. i cannot scroll the background, (which is what i want so good) however i cannot scroll to the top and bottom of the signup modal.. also i have the code for the modal at the bottom of my html code. so it brings me to the bottom of my page. Is there a way to get my modal to appear at the top of the page?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('modalSignin');
var btn = document.getElementById("signupButton");
 btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; // Prevent scrolling on the background
  }

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
      document.body.style.overflow = ""; // Enable scrolling on the background
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This does seem to prevent scrolling, and does bring the sreen right up to the top of the page, however the modal does not appear. i think it is appearing at the bottom, but i cant exactly tell. Do i need to position the modal with css before this works?

Comment: Your answer may be helpful, but it would be **much** more helpful with an explanation of why your code would help, and what problems in the original code it solves.

Comment: This is not how you manipulate a Bootstrap modal.